# Failure to join IPV6 multicast group on Windows 10

Tags: c++, networking, udp, multicast

The code below fails to join the IP multicast group address 0:0:0:0:0:ffff:efc0:202 which is the IPv4 address 239.192.2.2 converted to IPv6.

The failure occurs here:

```
 if (setsockopt(m_socket, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char*)&multicastRequest, sizeof(multicastRequest)) < 0)
 {
        int rc = WSAGetLastError();

        printf("Failed to join multicast group. Error = %d\n", rc);
 }
```

WSAGetLastError() returns 10049 ("The requested address is not valid in its context") which I find strange since the dual-mode socket is supposed to be able to receive UDP data from both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

If I try to do this:

```
if (setsockopt(m_socket, IPPROTO_IPV4, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char*)&multicastRequest, sizeof(multicastRequest)) < 0)
    {
        int rc = WSAGetLastError();

        printf("Failed to join multicast group. Error = %d\n", rc);
    }
```

it fails with error code rc = 10022 ("An invalid argument was supplied to the setsockopt")

The code was executed in MS Visual Studio 2015 on a Windows 10 machine.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")


void main(void)
{
    std::string ip = "0:0:0:0:0:ffff:efc0:202";
    WSADATA wsaData;
    struct ipv6_mreq multicastRequest;
    SOCKET m_socket;
    int off = 0;

    struct addrinfo* tmp = nullptr;
    struct addrinfo   hints = { 0 };

    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return;
    }

    hints.ai_family = AF_INET6;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;
    getaddrinfo(ip.c_str(), NULL, &hints, &tmp);


    m_socket = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    if (setsockopt(m_socket, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, (char*)&off, sizeof(off)) < 0)
    {
        int rc = WSAGetLastError();

        printf("Failed to set socket option IPV6_V6ONLY. Error = %d\n", rc);
    }

    memcpy(&multicastRequest.ipv6mr_multiaddr, &((struct sockaddr_in6*)(tmp->ai_addr))->sin6_addr, sizeof(multicastRequest.ipv6mr_multiaddr));

    multicastRequest.ipv6mr_interface = 0;

    if (setsockopt(m_socket, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char*)&multicastRequest, sizeof(multicastRequest)) < 0)
    {
        int rc = WSAGetLastError();

        printf("Failed to join multicast group. Error = %d\n", rc);
    }

   if (setsockopt(m_socket, IPPROTO_IPV4, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP (char*)&multicastRequest, sizeof(multicastRequest)) < 0)
    {
       int rc = WSAGetLastError();

       printf("Failed to join multicast group. Error = %d\n", rc);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean 'fails with 10049'? Setsockopt returns -1 in case of an error. IS it ERRNO value or what?

Comment: @SergeyA Sorry. Yes, it's WSAGetLastError() that returns 10049

Comment: Why is this post getting 2 votes for close? "Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.". The post meets these requirements.

Comment: Have you bothered to look up what error code 10049 from WinSock actually means?

Comment: Because you didn't post the MCVE (there is no code to call WSAGetLastError shown), and you didn't check what this error code means on Microsoft documentation website.

Comment: You didn't even mention that it was WinSock code in the question or tags...

Comment: FWIW, I've never tried it, but I'd be very surprised if it's even legal / possible to add an IPv4-mapped IPv6 address into an IPv6 multicast group.   IPv6 has its own specific ranges for multicast (ff00::/8)

Comment: I'll update the post and make it more clear

Comment: right, now try using a real IPv6 multicast address instead of a "fake" IPv4-mapped one and see if you get an error

Comment: @Alnitak I have updated the post

Comment: @Alnitak The code works fine with a real IPv6 multicast address. I am interested in knowing why it doesn't work with a converted IPv4 address? According to the articles I've read a dual-mode socket is capable of receiving UDP from both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses...That's what I'm trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Yes, I know.   IPv4 multicast and IPv6 multicast are not the same thing.   You'd probably have to use `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` to join the IPv4 equivalent multicast group.   Just because it can _receive_ in both protocols at once doesn't mean that options that can be applied to the IPv6 part of the socket will work for IPv4 specific ranges (and vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure your problem is caused by trying to add an IPv4 address (albeit encoded as an IPv4-mapped IPv6 address) to an IPv6 multicast group. 
Attempting to use `IPV6_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` in this way results in an `EINVAL` error on Linux.

Instead try using the appropriate `setsockopt()` call to add it to an IPv4 multicast group instead (i.e. using `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP`) using a normal `struct in_addr` containing a native IPv4 address instead of a `struct in6_addr` containing an IPv4-mapped address, e.g.

```
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;
getaddrinfo("224.0.0.251", NULL, &hints, &tmp);
struct sockaddr_in *in4 = (struct sockaddr_in*)tmp->ai_addr;
struct in_addr addr4 = in4->sin_addr;
struct ip_mreqn mreq4 = { 0 };
memcpy(&mreq4.imr_multiaddr, &addr4, sizeof addr4);
mreq4.imr_ifindex = 0;

if (setsockopt(m_socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mreq4, sizeof(mreq4)) < 0) {
        perror("setsockopt(IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP)");
        return -1;
}
```

With code based on yours (see https://pastebin.com/NBZ4KNYf) I have successfully created a dual stack socket and attached it separately to both an IPv6 multicast group and an IPv4 one, albeit on Linux, not Windows.

I was able to join both of the dns-sd (RFC 6763) multicast groups and receive packets over both IPv4 and IPv6.   In both cases the `recvfrom` call returned me an `AF_INET6` format address.

Comment: you'd probably have to pass the equivalent (real) IPv4 address too.

Comment: Ok, so it's possible to receive UDP from IPv4 and IPv6 addresses on a dual-mode socket and it's also possible to send UDP data to such addresses, but joining a multicast group to receive UDP data from an IPv4 address where the IP is specified as an address converted from IPv4 to IPv6 isn't possible. Where is the logic in that?

Comment: you also certainly can't pass an `ipv6_mreq` to an IPv4 multicast group setsockopt() call.

Comment: Correct, but it doesn't matter. I get the same error regardless.

Comment: IPv6 multicast has a lot of things that IPv4 multicast simply does not have. There are flags and scopes that you must use for IPv6 multicast, and getting those wrong could mess things up. In any case, IPv6 multicast must be in the `ff00::/8` range, and your converted IPv4 addresses are not in that range.